# Define variable value before running function

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, undefined

I have an array of arrays (a multi-dimensional array so to speak, `doors` in this example), in which `wait` and `point` are undefined.

```
var wait;
var point;
var doors = [
    [wait, doorWrap, 'regY', point, 10, 'bounceOut', 150, 5, 'bounceIn']
// ,[etc.]
];
```

I want to loop the `doors` array and for every iteration, execute the `key()` function, with the `doors` entries as arguments.

```
multiKey(doors, 500, 600);

function multiKey (keys, point, wait) {
    for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
            wait *= i;
            key.apply(this, keys[i]);
    }
}
```

Having passed `500` and `600` into the `multiKey()` function, I expected that `point` and `wait` would be defined before the `key()` function would run -- but heck, `point` and `wait` turn out to be `undefined`.

What is wrong? How could I go about solving this?

Sorry for the title too. I hope the question is clear enough though, because I had a hard time putting my problem into words! Thanks.

Comment: You don't define a `key` function anywhere. So that's probably why it's `undefined`... And that's the only real problem that you say you are having. It's not clear what you are after here.

Comment: @AlexWayne Sorry, I omitted the `key()` function here because I didn't think it was relevant. But it's in my code.

Comment: The `wait` in your `multiKey()` signature and the `wait` in your `doors` Arrays are different values.

Comment: Your only stated problem is that `key` is `undefined`, and you didn't think that included how to you define `key` is relevant? What is the code you have, and what exactly is wrong with it?

Comment: @AlexWayne: I think he's saying that `wait` and `point` are `undefined` inside the `key` function. Seems that there's an assumtion that all the `wait` identifiers will automatically resolve to the same memory.

Comment: @AlexWayne, yeah, sorry. Cleared the ambiguity in the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `wait` in your `multiKey()` signature and the `wait` in your `doors` Arrays are different values.

You could assign the values you're passing to each Array in the loop.

```
var doors = [
// --v--wait            --v--point
    [0, doorWrap, 'regY', 0, 10, 'bounceOut', 150, 5, 'bounceIn']
// ,[etc.]
];

multiKey(doors, 500, 600);

function multiKey (keys, point, wait) {
    for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
            keys[i][0] = wait * i;
            keys[i][3] = point
            key.apply(this, keys[i]);
    }
}
```

JavaScript doesn't have pointers, and its primitive types are always copied when assigned. As such, you're copying `undefiend` into the `doors` Arrays when you include `wait` and `point` in them.

Then when you pass the initial values to the `multiKey` function, they're being assigned to the `wait` and `point` parameters, which are entirely different. You're then multiplying the `wait` parameter by `i`, but again, that's a completely different value from that in the Arrays, so you're still just passing `undefined` from the Array.

Comment: Thanks @CrazyTrain! I actually tried this before. Somehow didn't get it to work then. Now it works perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

`point` and `wait` are *declared* but not defined.

I see no operation on `point`.

Comment: I passed `500` and `600` as `point` and `wait` respectively as parameters to the `multiKey` function. A `console.log` does return `500` and `600`, but it just isn't passed to the `key` function.